# Golang sql package queries slower than PostgreSQL SQL queries

Tags: sql, postgresql, go

I am using Golang SQL package for making calls to my database. I am using prepared statements, and having index on column

```
stmtHas := db.Prepare(`SELECT value FROM `+tableName+` WHERE key = $1;`)
now     := time.Now()
err     := db.stmtGet.QueryRow(key).Scan(&value)  
elapsed := time.Since(now)
fmt.Println(elapsed)
```

This prints-

> 40.874782ms

However raw SQL query is taking very less time compared to this.

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) SELECT value FROM tableName WHERE key = 'some_key';
```

gives-

> Planning time: 0.062 ms
>   Execution time: 0.040 ms

Is the difference in these time normal? If not, how can I optimize it?

Comment: I don't think the execution time of `EXPLAIN` can be compared to actually executing the query. `EXPLAIN` only tells you what PostgreSQL *would* do in case you executed the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is really comparing apples to oranges. The Go code time represents the time to send the query to PostgreSQL, the time it takes to execute the query in PostgreSQL, and the time it takes for the response to return and be processed. The EXPLAIN command only represents the time it takes to execute the query in PostgreSQL.